# How expensive are matrix multiplications?

Tags: performance, rotation, matrix-multiplication

I've written a couple of methods in my Quad class to draw quads and also to rotate.

Currently, the draw sprite method does just that - renders the quad to the screen.

However, the rotation method, rotates **and** also renders the quad.

I've got another couple of methods written, one that just rotates but doesn't render, and another render routine that takes the rotation matrix into account when doing it's matrix multiplications.  So, instead of doing this:

```
Quad sprite = new Quad();
Quad sprite.rotate(0,0,45,mMVPMatrix);  //rotate by 45 degrees and render at 0,0
```

I can do this:

```
Quad sprite = new Quad();
sprite.rotate(45);            //Rotate sprite by 45 degrees
sprite.draw(0,0,mMVPMatrix);  //Render sprite at 0,0
```

Although the latter is somewhat more flexible when writing my main code it does mean that even if I don't want to rotate a sprite, the draw routine, still has to take the rotation matrix and combine it with the projection matrix.

When I have 50+ sprites going, will this cost me?  I know there is always a trade-off between 'more code' and 'better performance' but realistically, would this be a huge problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the code first. Then see if performance is an issue. Far too many things can affect performance for anyone to give you even a hint, especially without any real code (other than the tiny fragment you've posted) to judge by.

Someone else here said that the biggest sin in code development is early optimization. You can spend a lot of time early on optimizing code that never would have been a problem. You can always optimize after the fact and after the fact you'll have actual information about where your bottlenecks are instead of early optimizations that will result in tweaked code that never would have become a bottleneck, but is now less readable because of the optimizations.

Comment: Thanks @Pete, I was just after an idea really of how to approach this, but you're absolutly right of course, over-optimisation is bad so I will go with the 2nd option, and keep the other one on stand-by in case of performance issues further down the line - thanks :-)